# Backup audit database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

We currently have SQL Server 2000 in use. One is LIVE and one is BACKUP. We have an audit database which grows massively. What would be ideal is that at the end of each month, the data gets copied from LIVE to BACKUP and the LIVE data to be flushed (hope this makes sense so far)

I was told you can do this in a number ways but one way I found interesting was to split each month into a different data file and then at the end of the month to move the data file over and create a new one for the next month - any advice on this, or any other solution would be appreciated

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 1):

The technique you are refering to is called Table Partitioning. However, that is not available in SQ Server 2000. To the best of my knowledge, it was introduced in SQL Server 2005:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

However, you could build similar functionality by means of scripting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902650%28v=sql.80%29.aspx